# .NET Core 5 model validation : FOR NOT nullable DATA TYPE - the value '' is invalid error

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to use model validation in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC and can't manage to replace this default error message:

> The value " is invalid

This also didn't work.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

There're two accessor's default value is   `The value " is invalid`,try set as below

```
services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            
            options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
                _ => "Your message.");
            options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInValidAccessor(
                _ => "Your message.");
        });
```

and make sure the message was not `The value " is invalid for ""`,it's related with another accssor  `AttemptValueIsInValidAccessor`

If you still have problem with it ,please show more details